# How to tracing heap memory leak problem in ESP32?

Tags: esp32

I am using ESP32 chip to develop a project, but I found that the heap size seems to steadily decrease. I have used the:

```
MDF_LOGD("the free heap size is %d --root_write_task(start)", esp_get_minimum_free_heap_size());
```

to check every function in the main program, but still cannot find any leakage point and the IDF APP Tracer seems to be not working at all. Basically I have no output at all.

I am quite worried that I have cloned some driver to my program and caused this issue. AIs there any other way to check such an issue? I am using VSCode with the esp-idf extension.

Answer (score 1):

The correct function to call to get the heap size is [esp_get_free_heap_size()](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/system.html#_CPPv422esp_get_free_heap_sizev).
The best way to check for memory leaks is to connect your device with JTAG and debug it in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some great resources which could help you on this.

[Memory Management - FreeRTOS](https://www.freertos.org/a00111.html)

[Mastering the FreeRTOS Real Time Kernel](https://www.freertos.org/fr-content-src/uploads/2018/07/161204_Mastering_the_FreeRTOS_Real_Time_Kernel-A_Hands-On_Tutorial_Guide.pdf)

[Heap Memory Debugging - Espressif](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/heap_debug.html)